# Declare fast api, python's object

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

Can we declare a model that inherits basemodel and put a value in it, not a normal Python model?

I can forcefully create a PyTimeZoneSetting model, but can I use the existing TimeZoneSetting?

```py
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    from typing import List, Optional

    class TimeZoneSetting(BaseModel):
        time_zone: str
        type: int
        sync_time: Optional[str] = None
        time_server: Optional[str] = None
        time_set_type: Optional[int] = None

    class PyTimeZoneSetting():
        time_zone: str
        type: int
        sync_time: str
        time_server: str
        time_set_type: str

    def update_system_timezone():
        !Here, I want to create a TimeZoneSetting model and put in a value.!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure of your intentions bu I will try to provide an example which could fulfill your needs.

Here are some ways you could initialize your Pydantic Model:

```
# initialize every field one by one
model_instance = TimeZoneSetting(time_zone="foo", type=1, sync_time="bar")

# provide your dict object
kwargs = {"time_zone": "foo", "type": 1}
model_instance = TimeZoneSetting(**kwargs)
```

Here is the way to update your model, where every field is reached as an attribute to your class:

```
model_instance.time_zone = "bar"
```

Here is the way to get you model as a dict:

```
model_instance.dict()
```

Comment: thank you.
I need to set the time zone,
I want to set the system time myself or use ntpdate to synchronize the server.
The answers you provided helped me with my problem.